# How to update the row in my AddViewController with the new name

Tags: swift, swift3, uikit

I want to update the Row name in my itemViewController from the AddViewController. In my code I am passing the item object that contains the name and description to my AddViewController and changing the values however the rows name never gets updated.

I looked around the internet and found information on what is called the delegate pattern to do this. I'm just not sure how to implement that pattern. Thank you for the help in advance.

```
//  ItemsViewController.swift
//  Project 3-ToDo
//
//  Created by Gracias Claude on 10/9/20.
//

import UIKit

class ItemsViewController : UITableViewController {
    var itemStore: ItemStore!
    
    
    
    @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // Create a new item and add it to the store
        let newItem = itemStore.createItem()

        // Figure out where that item is in the array
        if let index = itemStore.allItems.firstIndex(of: newItem) {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

            // Insert this new row into the table
            tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
       }

       @IBAction func toggleEditingMode(_ sender: UIButton) {
        // If you are currently in editing mode...
           if isEditing {
               // Change text of button to inform user of state
               sender.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)

               // Turn off editing mode
               setEditing(false, animated: true)
           } else {
               // Change text of button to inform user of state
               sender.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)

               // Enter editing mode
               setEditing(true, animated: true)
           }
       }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
            numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return itemStore.allItems.count
    }
    
    // returning table view cell
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
            cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        

            // Get a new or recycled cell
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UITableViewCell",
                for: indexPath)

        // Set the text on the cell with the description of the item
        // that is at the nth index of items, where n = row this cell
        // will appear in on the table view
        let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "\(item.dateCreated)"

        return cell
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle,
                            forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // If the table view is asking to commit a delete command...
        if editingStyle == .delete {
            let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]

            // Remove the item from the store
            itemStore.removeItem(item)

            // Also remove that row from the table view with an animation
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                            moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                            to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
        // Update the model
        itemStore.moveItem(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // If the triggered segue is the "showItem" segue
        switch segue.identifier {
        case "showItem":
            print("Hello World")
            // Figure out which row was just tapped
            if let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row {

                // Get the item associated with this row and pass it along
                let item = itemStore.allItems[row]
                let detailViewController
                        = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
                detailViewController.item = item
            }
            break;
        
        case "addItem":
            let row = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row ?? 0

//                // Get the item associated with this row and pass it along
                let item = itemStore.allItems[row]
                let addViewController
                        = segue.destination as! AddViewController
                addViewController.item = item
//            }
            break;
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected segue identifier.")
        }
    }
}

//AddViewController

//
//  AddViewController.swift
//  Project 3-ToDo
//
//  Created by Gracias Claude on 10/9/20.
//

import UIKit

class AddViewController : UIViewController {
    
    
    var item: Item!;
   
  
    @IBOutlet weak var itemNameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var priorityField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionField: UITextField!
    
    
    @IBAction func submitItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //how to update the existing Row name
        item.name = itemNameField.text ?? "Default Text"
        item.description = descriptionField.text ?? "default Description"
        
        return;
      
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding, you are passing data from Your `ItemViewController` to the `AddViewController`. You then change that value from the `AddViewController` and you want that change reflected back to the `ItemViewController`.

If that's the case, you have to pass back that data you've modified back to the `ItemViewController` and there are a number of ways to do that.

The easiest ways to do that (not the best practice in my opinion) is to create a function inside your `ItemViewController` that will capture the new changes.

```
func captureModified(itemStore: ItemStore) {
     self.itemStore = itemStore
}
```

Next, when you transition from `ItemViewController` to `AddViewController`, create an instance of the `ItemViewController` within `AddViewController` and initialize that when you transition from `ItemViewController` to the `AddViewController`.

```
class AddViewController: UIViewController {
     weak var itemViewController: ItemViewController?
}
```

Transition from `ItemViewController` to `AddViewController`

```
let addViewController = segue.destination as! AddViewController
addViewController.itemViewController = self
```

Finally, when you transition back; you can either do this in the `deinit` method or create your own back method in the `AddViewController` method.

```
deinit {
     itemViewController.captureModified(itemStore: itemStore)
}
```

That's the easiest way to do things. The safest and best practice is to wrap the `captureModified(_:)` method in a protocol and create an instance of that protocol instead of the entire `ItemViewController` class. Let me know if you prefer that, and I can implement it. Or maybe I'll put it regardless for future readers when time permits.

Comment: So I'm not passing in the item store just the item

Comment: UPDATING ONLY THE FIRST ROW 
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "added":
        
    let itemsViewController = segue.destination as! ItemsViewController
        itemsViewController.itemStore = itemStore

    default:
    preconditionFailure("Unexpected segue identifier.")
    }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I added a new `segue` to the `AddViewController` back to the `itemViewController`

```
   switch segue.identifier {
   case "added":
       
   let itemsViewController = segue.destination as! ItemsViewController
       itemsViewController.itemStore = itemStore

   default:
   preconditionFailure("Unexpected segue identifier.")
```

Kept track of the cell index in `itemsViewController`

```
 @IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton) {
     // Create a new item and add it to the store
     let newItem = itemStore.createItem()

     // Figure out where that item is in the array
     if let index = itemStore.allItems.firstIndex(of: newItem) {
         let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
         self.row = index

         // Insert this new row into the table
         tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
     }
    }
```

And passed the `AddViewController` the correct row that was being updated so that the `ItemViewController` knew which one was being updated

```
            
            let row = self.row

//                // Get the item associated with this row and pass it along
                let item = itemStore.allItems[row]
            let itemStore = self.itemStore;
                let addViewController
                        = segue.destination as! AddViewController
                addViewController.item = item
            addViewController.itemStore = itemStore
            addViewController.row = self.row;
//            }
            break;
        default:
            preconditionFailure("Unexpected segue identifier.")
        }
```

I also added this at the top of the `AddViewController` to have an instance of the `itemViewController`   `weak var itemViewController: ItemsViewController?`